# how do i list all the perms of a pre defined role?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam

I see this crap in lots of google docs:
[image]

They are doing a terrible job with documentation here.

I want to create a custom role. custom roles dont support adding predefined roles and dont support wildcard permissions. I NEED to know ALL the perms of a predefined role

is there a gcloud command for this? why is info so hard to find? i must be missing something

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an equivalent gcloud command and it is `gcloud iam roles list`. You can check its documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles/list) to find more options or parameters on the command.

With regards to gcloud command for creating custom roles, you will need to use `gcloud iam roles create`. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role) is a more detailed guide for this one.